# Como diferenciar as sessões nas guias do navegador?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, jsp, session, servlet

Em um aplicativo web implementado em Java usando JSP e Servlets, se eu armazenar informações na sessão do usuário, essa informação é compartilhada de todas as abas do mesmo navegador. Como diferenciar as sessões nas guias do navegador?

Neste exemplo:

```html
<%@page language="java"%>
<%
String user = request.getParameter("user");
user = (user == null ? (String)session.getAttribute("SESSIONS_USER") : user);
session.setAttribute("SESSIONS_USER",user);
%>
<html><head></head><body>
<%=user %>
<form method="post">
User:<input name="user" value="">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Copie este código em uma página JSP (`testpage.jsp`), implemente esse arquivo em um contexto existente de um aplicativo da Web no servidor (eu uso o Apache Tomcat) e, em seguida, abra um navegador (FF, IE7 ou Opera) usando o URL correto (`localhost/context1/testpage.jsp`), digite seu nome na entrada e envie o formulário. Em seguida, abra uma nova guia no mesmo navegador e, em seguida, você pode ver seu nome (obter a partir da sessão) na nova guia. Tenha cuidado com a cache do navegador, às vezes parece que isso não acontece, mas está no cache, atualize a segunda guia.

Comment: "*FF, IE7 ou Opera*" - Por que um dinossauro como IE7!?

Comment: olha, um amigo na faculdade um curso de 20h de IE7 e aceitaram @VictorStafusa então pra alguns não é tão dinossauro rs